# Insert NSMutableDictionary into 1 cell of SQLite database

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I'm hoping someone here might be able to help me out.

I need to insert a NSMutableDictionary into one cell of a SQLite database. I am able to insert strings etc into the database, but when I try and insert a Dictionary I get a syntax error:

```
**Can't run query 'BEGIN TRANSACTION; UPDATE Database SET Column1 = {
Bad = "";
"End_Time" = 4;
Good = "";
Moderate = "";
Note = "";
} WHERE Title = Name; COMMIT TRANSACTION;' error message: unrecognized token: "{"**
```

To do this I am using the following code:

```
NSString *sql2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE Database SET Column%@ = %@ WHERE Title = %@",previousQuestion,adictionary,Name];
```

Can anyone help or suggest a different approach,? I need to be able to store the key/values in 1 cell, as there will be 79 more cells with similar data and I need to reference each specific key from a specific column of the database.

I've tried turning the Dictionary into a string (and then I'd turn the string back to a dictionary on retrieval) But this causes the same issue.
Any suggestions?

Many thanks,
Andrew

Comment: You cannot insert Objective-C objects into a SQLite database.  You can only insert numbers, strings, and "blobs" (binary data strings).  Generally what you want to do is to map each dictionary key/value to the corresponding column in the DB, but that takes a bit of work (if you don't have one of several "canned" DB packages to use).

Comment: (The other thing you can do is convert the dictionary to JSON and insert the JSON as a character string, but that doesn't allow a DB user to access the individual values in the dictionary.)

Answer (score 9):

Their is two way you can do this.
**1st way** :-

Archive your NSMutableDictionary convert it into NSData and store it in your Sqlite column which datatype should have be blob type. Archiving something like this,

```
 NSData *theDictionaryData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourDictionary];
```

Bind this data in sqlite,

```
sqlite3_bind_blob(addStmt, 5, theDictionaryData, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Now retrieving time from sqlite,

```
NSData *retrieveData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(selectstmt, 4) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(selectstmt, 4)];
```

and finally convert it into NSDictionary,

```
 NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:retrieveData];
```

**2nd way** :-
Create numbers of column those are equal to numbers of keys of NSDictionary. Bring data from every key and save it respective table column.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just insert an Objective-C object into the database. It must be a string, binary data, or a number. In converting it to a string, you also need to sanitize the input (so that it doesn't contain any invalid characters that SQL will interpret in another way). For example, if you tried to insert a string that was some SQL code, you wouldn't want it to try to execute that code. It looks like here it's getting hung up on a `{` in the string. You could instead convert the dictionary or the string to NSData and insert it into the database as binary data.

Comment: There is no problem with the "{" if one uses a "prepared" statement.